Вычесть из суммы всех нечётных по порядку цифр сумму всех чётных по порядку
Нумерация цифр начинается с единицы и идёт справа налево. Приведенный ниже код - неверный.
n = input()
T = 0
i = 0
while i < len(n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        T += int(n[i])
    else:
        T -= int(n[i])
    i = i + 1
print(T)


Приведите пример прямо в вопросе: входные данные такие-то, в результате должно получиться то-то. Чтобы не было разногласий в формулировке вопроса.

n - вводимое пользователем число, T - ответ, сумма всех нечетных по порядку минус сумма всех четных по порядку.

откуда известно, что неверный?

@Эникейщик Он считает элементы слева направо, а нужно наоборот. Ну и индекс с 0 начинается, а не с 1.

Если ваш код подправить:
n = input()
leng = len(n)
T = 0
for i in range(len(n)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        T += int(n[leng-1-i])
    else:
        T -= int(n[leng-1-i])
print(T)

А можно и так:
n = int(input())
s = [0,0]
d = 1
while n:
    s[d%2] += n%10
    n //= 10
    d += 1
print(s[1]-s[0])


@CrazyElf   индекс берётся n[leng-1-i]

Всё, дошло. Индекс в одну сторону считается, а элементы берутся с другой стороны. Тяжеловато осознать, но да, это работает.

Ну код то написать не сложно. Только боюсь вы его не сможете преподавателю объяснить.
print(sum(int((i % 2 - 0.5) * 2) * int(x) for i, x in enumerate(reversed(input()), 1)))

